# How to animate image sequence when hovering left/right using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new in jquery and I want to include some design on my frontpage. But I can't find any good resource or example how can I do this.

I have set of images that is taken by sequence. The image is like a bouncing ball. Now I have a link or anchor tag. And what I want is when the user is moving his mouse right. The image sequence will increment meaning if I have an image like this ball1.jpg the next is ball2.jpg, etc.. if the mouse hover to the left it will decrement up to the first image which is ball1.jpg.

I have this simple code.

```
<div id="image_container">
    <!-- should be replace if hovering -->       
    <img src="/sample_layout/images/ball1.jpg" />  <!-- this is the default image -->
    <img src="/sample_layout/images/ball2.jpg" />  <!-- this will replace if hover -->
    <img src="/sample_layout/images/ball3.jpg" />  <!-- this will replace if hover -->
    <img src="/sample_layout/images/ball4.jpg" />  <!-- this will replace if hover -->
    <img src="/sample_layout/images/ball5.jpg" />  <!-- this will replace if hover -->
</div>

<ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="dropdown">HOME</a></li><!-- This will be the link I need to hover -->
      <li class="sublinks">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>        
      </li> 
</ul>
```

Here's what i want to do here is the link example

http://www.dior.com/couture/home/en_gb

That's all guys. Can you give me any reference how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mousemove` event to calculate percent and decide which image you want to show. This example uses colors instead of images, you can change to images.
http://jsfiddle.net/h84Pj/

```
var screenWidth;
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow'];

function onMouseMove(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    var color = colors[parseInt(x / screenWidth * colors.length)];
    $(document.body).css('background-color', color);
}

function onResize() {
    screenWidth = $(document).width();
}

$(window).on('mousemove', onMouseMove);
$(window).resize(onResize);
onResize();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am looking to do the same. 
I have 29 separate images which are all approximately between 250KB - 350KB.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8hw4mok/1/) link to check out the progress..

```
var screenWidth;
var imgblock = ['https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v1.jpg', 
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v2.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v3.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v4.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v5.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v6.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v7.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v8.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v9.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v10.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v11.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v12.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v13.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v14.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v15.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v16.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v17.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v18.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v19.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v20.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v21.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v22.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v23.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v24.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v25.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v26.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v27.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v28.jpg',
            'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1835/0713/files/v29.jpg'];

function onMouseMove(e) {
var x = e.pageX;
var theimg = imgblock[parseInt(x / screenWidth * imgblock.length)];
$('.verve-seq').css("background-image", "url('" + theimg + "')");
}

function onResize() {
screenWidth = $(document).width();
}

$(window).on('mousemove', onMouseMove);
$(window).resize(onResize);
onResize();
```

There is one major issue that I have. It seems that each img array loads seperatly, which removes the background for a millisecond which gives quick flash of white when you mouseover from left to right and vice versa. (not recommended for people with epilepsy :/)

I found this concept on [the north face website](https://www.thenorthface.com/en_ca/featured/apex-flex.html?cm_sp=HPHero-_-Homepage-_-S18ApexFlex&banner=S18ApexFlex.Homepage.Spring18.HPHero)

Comment: Here is an update though it still has flashes while loading the css background images, the flashes are not constant and get removed after the first images are load from the css. https://jsfiddle.net/qaaef7cL/1/